# Setting hibernate 'default-cascade' property globally

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, cascade

I'm using Spring and Hibernate with annotations. I want to set the [`default-cascade`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-mapping) property for all classes like this in my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="all"/>
```

After some debugging it seems this doesn't work unless I define the classes and properties explicitly in the mapping file, and since I'm working with annotations everywhere else I'd really like to avoid that. Is it possible to set `default-cascade` globally without explicitly specifying properties?

Comment: what do you mean with it doesnt work ? what is your case ?

Comment: Cascade style remains "none" for all classes and fields (except those explicitly annotated with CASCADE annotation). I want cascade to be "all" as default without having to explicitly annotate (or specify in mapping file) every class and property.

Answer (score 1):

you can set it on the configuration object. pseudocode

```
config = buildHibernateConfiguration();

for (ClassMap clazz : config.getClassMappings())
{
    clazz.getPropertyIterator();
}
```

Comment: Tried it (although getting the Hibernate Configuration object from Spring was a bit tricky). Set cascade value of all properties to "all" but it doesn't seem to have any effect. After some low-level debugging it seems the Property.cascade field is only used in the constructor of the `AbstractEntityPersister`class (which then stores all cascade info of the entity in a private field) - so it's only relevant when Configuration is created and not later.

Comment: entitypersistor should be created later on buildSessionfactory. AFAIK it is not present in the configuration object. also note only associations (references, collections) can have a cascade setting, it is ignored on all others. Use clazz.collectionIterator to get collections